# Flask_SQLAlchemy select, where, scalar, connection_execute

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I wonder how can i compose request like shown below using SQLalchemy without Flask extension but with options to attract value (result) in template:

```
class Finance(db.Model):
    __tablename__=='MAIN'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    month = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cost_with_vat = db.Column(db.Integer)
    profit = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I want to write  the same request  like i could do it through SQLAlchemy (i wrote it below), without Flask extension.

```
profit = select([func.sum(order.columns.profit)])
profit = profit.where(or_(
         order.columns.cost_with_vat>0,
        order.columns.cost_with_vat=='?'))

profit_month = profit.where(order.columns.month==11)
result = connection.execute(profit_month).scalar()
```

Need to show result in template

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<h1>{{result}}</h1>'''
```